# Selenium webdriver unknown error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using protractor for doing some e2e tests but despite the tests run successfully the selenium-webdriver is throwing an error after they complete.

```
.../node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
var template = new Error(this.message);
               ^
UnknownError: no such session
...
```

I'm having problems figuring out what am I doing wrong.

EDIT: I was able to find that the problem was that I was doing a browser.close() for measuring some testing times.
How can I close and reopen the browser without breaking the tests, because doing browser.close() and then browser.get() is not working?

EDIT: With protractor 3.3.0 this is now possible using browser.restart()

Comment: Do you intend on using a 'fresh' instance of webdriver for each test? `.close()` will close an open 'window' but it doesn't kill a webdriver process, `.quit()`, on the other hand, does.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a new instance of the webdriver, I want to close and open a new window, but when I use the `.close()` it fails with UnknownError: no such session.